# Tkinter frame showing up outside its parent

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to grid a label inside its parent frame but it instead shows up at the bottom of the window, nowhere that I can think is even related to where I told it to go.
Here is my code:

```
class Window:
def __init__(self, root):
    #configure the window as root
    self.root = root

    #create a canvas
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, bg="white", width=500, height=300).grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)

    #create two frames to the right of the canvas for entering letters and displaying wrong guesses
    self.wrong_guess_frame = Frame(self.root, bg="red", width=150, height=150).grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.entry_frame = Frame(self.root, bg="green", width=150, height=150).grid(row=1, column=1)

    #create a title label for the wrong answers and a frame in which to sit it
    self.wrngguess_title_frame = Frame(self.wrong_guess_frame, bg="blue",width = 100).grid()
    self.wrngguess_title = Label(self.wrong_guess_frame, text="Wrong Guesses:").grid()
```

The last two lines are what I'm having trouble with. The `self.wrngguess_title` appears not in the `wrong_guess_frame` but at the bottom of the window, and I can't figure out what's causing that.

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1):

`self.wrong_guess_frame` does NOT refer to any frame; this variable is in fact `None`, the return value of the `.grid()` method you applied to the frame after you created it.  And `None`, as the first parameter to any widget constructor, gets interpreted as a reference to the root window.

You have to do the widget creation and grid/pack as two separate statements if you want to also have a variable refer to the widget:

```
self.wrong_guess_frame = Frame(self.root, bg="red", width=150, height=150)
self.wrong_guess_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, based on what you specified in the quesiton, all you need to do is specify the `row` and the `column` to be the same as the frame, like so:

```
    self.wrngguess_title = Label(self.wrong_guess_frame, text="Wrong Guesses:").grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.wrngguess_title_frame = Frame(self.wrong_guess_frame, bg="blue",width = 100).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

The preceeding code produces the following result:
[image: Result]

But if you want to move the line down a bit, use the following snippet:

```
self.wrngguess_title_frame = Frame(self.wrong_guess_frame, bg="blue",width = 100).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(25,10))
```

Which produces this result: [image: Result]

Hope that helps you out. That's what I deduced you wanted from your question.